# Binding to an element of the DataTemplate on Windows Phone

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, data-binding

Plain and simple: I need to bind some properties of the `ContextMenu` items to a property of their parent in the `DataTemplate`.

I can't find a way to access it because `ElementName` doesn't work and `RelativeSource` allows me to use just `Self` or `TemplatedParent`.

Here's my code:

```
<telerikPrimitives:RadDataBoundListBox Grid.Row="2"
                                       Grid.Column="0"
                                       Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                                       ItemsSource="{Binding Transfers.Keys, Source={StaticResource TransfersManager}, Mode=OneWay}">
                <telerikPrimitives:RadDataBoundListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <toolkit:TransferControl x:Name="TransferControl"
                            Header="{Binding Converter={StaticResource TransferMonitorToDocumentTitleConverter}}"
                            IsContextMenuEnabled="False"
                            Icon="{Binding Converter={StaticResource TransferMonitorToDocumentIconUriConverter}}"
                            AutoHide="False"
                            Monitor="{Binding}"
                            Language="it-IT"
                            StatusTextBrush="Black"
                            Foreground="Black">
                            <toolkit:TransferControl.HeaderTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel>
                                        <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                                            <toolkit:ContextMenu>
                                                <toolkit:MenuItem Header="item1"
                                                                  IsEnabled="{Binding Monitor Property in the TransferControl object}"
                                                                  />
                                                <toolkit:MenuItem Header="item2"/>
                                            </toolkit:ContextMenu>
                                        </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                                        <Rectangle Fill="Transparent" Height="30"/>
                                        <ContentControl Content="{Binding}"
                                                        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                        Foreground="Black" />                                        
                     </StackPanel>
                 </DataTemplate>
             </toolkit:TransferControl.HeaderTemplate>
         </toolkit:TransferControl>
     </DataTemplate>
</telerikPrimitives:RadDataBoundListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

What I'm trying to bind is:

```
<toolkit:MenuItem Header="item1" 
                  IsEnabled="{Binding Monitor Property in the TransferControl object}"
                  />
```

and I'd like to bind it to the `Monitor` property of the `<toolkit:TransferControl x:Name="TransferControl" ... />` object.

Comment: have you tried `IsEnabled="{Binding DataContext.Monitor, ElementName=TransferControl}"`. I have not tested it when the element is inside a DataTemplate of another item, but I have used this approach when binding to a ListBox or other ItemsControl like in [this post](http://www.visuallylocated.com/post/2014/05/29/Migrating-from-the-Windows-Phone-Toolkit-ContextMenu-to-the-new-Runtime-MenuFlyout.aspx)

Comment: I can't try it now, but if I'm not wrong it will throw an exception saying that there's no `TransferControl` element because it's defined inside a `DataTemplate`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this my simply creating a new UserControl that holds the content of your ListBox. I used the LongListSelector. Here is a solution that works.

First the XAML for the page:

```
<phone:LongListSelector Margin="0,0,-12,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <local:WindowsPhoneControl/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
</phone:LongListSelector>
```

Then the UserControl. This was nothing special, just a wrapper.

```
    <UserControl x:Class="PivotApp1.WindowsPhoneControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    d:DesignHeight="480" d:DesignWidth="480">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="{StaticResource PhoneChromeBrush}">
        <phone:LongListSelector x:Name="TransferControl" Margin="0,0,-12,0"
                                ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                                toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True">
            <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                            <toolkit:ContextMenu>
                                <toolkit:MenuItem Header="item1"
                                                  IsEnabled="{Binding DataContext.Monitor, ElementName=TransferControl}"/>
                                <toolkit:MenuItem Header="item2"/>
                            </toolkit:ContextMenu>
                        </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                        <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,17">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding LineOne}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding LineTwo}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="12,-6,12,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
        </phone:LongListSelector>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

With this solution the Monitor property was hit when rendering the list. It will not be hit when opening the menu. Of course if you fire the propertyChanged for monitor, it will get the value again.

Comment: While I also liked @yasen's solution, I decided to give the bounty to you because yours seems a kind of solution that can be used in every kind of scenario.

Comment: Shawn, may I ask what do you think about my solution (if you have the time to take a look at it - only the part after **Update**)? I'm just curious. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

The property you want to bind to seems to be bound to the DataContext itself. Why not just bind to it (the DataContext) in the HeaderTemplate? All you need to do is bind the Header property to the DataContext, instead of converting it to something else, and then use the Converter inside the HeaderTemplate. Something like this:

```
<telerikPrimitives:RadDataBoundListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <toolkit:TransferControl x:Name="TransferControl"
                    Header="{Binding}"
                    IsContextMenuEnabled="False"
                    Icon="{Binding Converter={StaticResource TransferMonitorToDocumentIconUriConverter}}"
                    AutoHide="False"
                    Monitor="{Binding}"
                    Language="it-IT"
                    StatusTextBrush="Black"
                    Foreground="Black">
            <toolkit:TransferControl.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                            <toolkit:ContextMenu>
                                <toolkit:MenuItem Header="item1"
                                                            IsEnabled="{Binding}"
                                                            />
                                <toolkit:MenuItem Header="item2"/>
                            </toolkit:ContextMenu>
                        </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                        <Rectangle Fill="Transparent" Height="30"/>
                        <ContentControl Content="{Binding Converter={StaticResource TransferMonitorToDocumentTitleConverter}}"
                                                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                Foreground="Black" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </toolkit:TransferControl.HeaderTemplate>
        </toolkit:TransferControl>
    </DataTemplate>
</telerikPrimitives:RadDataBoundListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

On a side note, I think you may be doing too much binding. Bindings and converters can lead to bad performance and sometimes it's just faster and easier to do things without bindings.

Btw, may I ask what does the TransferMonitorToDocumentTitleConverter do?

**Update**

It seems there is a bug in the toolkit. The Header property's getter casts the object to string and so, even though the property is of type object, you can only set it to a string - otherwise an exception is thrown in the getter, which is used internally.

Here's a possible workaround:

1. Extend the TransferControl like this:

   ```
   public class TransferControlFixed : TransferControl {
       public static readonly DependencyProperty HeaderFixedProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("HeaderFixed", typeof(object), typeof(TransferControlFixed), new PropertyMetadata(null));
       public object HeaderFixed {
           get {
               return GetValue(HeaderFixedProperty);
           }
           set {
               SetValue(HeaderFixedProperty, value);
           }
       }

       public override void OnApplyTemplate() {
           base.OnApplyTemplate();

           var control = (ContentControl)this.GetTemplateChild("Header");
           control.SetBinding(ContentControl.ContentProperty, new Binding() {
               Path = new PropertyPath("HeaderFixed"),
               Source = this
           });
       }
   }
   ```
2. Use TransferControlFixed instead of TransferControl and bind the HeaderFixed instead of the Header property.

It seems like a reasonably simple workaround.

Comment: Using you code, the bound property gets the value of `TransferControl`'s `Header` while I need it to get the `Monitor` one. The converter is something left from an old version of the page, I'm not using it anymore.

Comment: @StepTNT Aren't Monitor and Header the same thing with my code? They are both bound to the DataContext object, which I assume is a TransferMonitor object, right? So the bound property should have the same value as the Monitor property.

Comment: But they can't be the same thing. `Header` is a `string` and `Monitor` is a `TransferMonitor`, that's why I'm using a converter on `Header`. With no converter on `Header` it throws an exception saying that `TransferMonitor` can't be converted to `string`. But, with the converter, the `MenuItem.IsEnabled` binding receives a `string` and not a `TransferMonitor`

Comment: @StepTNT Oh god.. that toolkit... The type of the Header property is object, not string. But in the [getter of the property](http://phone.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit/TransferControl/TransferControl.cs) there's a cast to string... because why not. I'll think about something else, but this should've been the solution!

Comment: They now how to cause pain :D If you don't come up with a working solution, I think I'll build my own `TransferControl` component to remove that cast, but I'd like to see if there's another way before changing their code

Comment: @StepTNT I edited my answer and proposed a workaround which seems reasonably simple to me. I can't think of something less hacky at the moment. You could of course just copy the class or rebuild the library.

Comment: I took some time to try it and it seem to work, but what if I need a converter on the `Header` property? Because I need one to format my `TransferMonitor`'s name, but using it leads back to the problem in which `IsEnabled` receives a `string`

Comment: @StepTNT Why would you *need* a converter on the `HeaderFixed` property? Just use the converter in the template where you bind the ContentControl's Content property. There is only one object that is DataContext of the HeaderTemplate and if you pass a string there, you won't be able to get anything but that string. That's why you normally pass the whole object and inside the template bind to the parts that you need.